# Inserting a nifi record with date type field into PutMongo

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-nifi, jolt

Im trying to add a date field to a JSON record and insert it to mongo using `PutMongo` processor (I succedded to do so using PutMongoRecord but when Im using PutMongo processor the field type is string and not date because there is no use of the `JsonTreeReader`)...I need the PutMongo processor to insert this field as a date in order to put a TTL index on it...

Currently I used `JoltTransform` and some variations of `UpdateRecord` but I only managed to convert the date to a timestamp which doesn't help me...

Is there a way to convert a string or a timestamp to a date field and insert it to mongo as a date field with the `PutMongo` processor?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Update record is the way to go - see doco here http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#predicates - use the recordpath to edit/format your data , if format does not work use substring and the switch to date

Comment: The problem is that every changed field is a string at the end of the coversion...for example, after converting to date it will be a string in the flowfile itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you stick to `PutMongoRecord`. You haven't said why you prefer to use `PutMongo`, but if you need to add some fields to enable that TTL index it's as simple as adding some optional attributes in your schema and calling `UpdateRecord` to put them in there before doing the put.